# How add related nodes to content profile?

Tags: nodes, 6

In Drupal 6, I am trying to list the links to nodes created by that user and/or nodes which have her name in their tags below the profile. But I could not figure out how to do either. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I will recommend to use this service from Addthis - https://www.addthis.com/get/recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can load nodes by various parameters. Just give the parameters which you want to load.
[See here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7#comment-32933) Here is for Drupal 6 also.

If you had a code in D6 to load a node using an array of conditions to match against in the database query like this:

```
<?php
$param = array(
    'type' => 'your_node_type',
    'title' => 'your node title',
    'status' => 1,
);
$node = node_load($param);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To list content owned by a user you should ...

1. create a View that lists content
2. create a Relationship in that view to the User that owns that content
3. create a Block Display within that view
4. configure an "Argument" for that view which "Provides Default" and grabs the UID of the User from the URL
5. place that block using some mechanism for Block placement on each User Page.

hope that general recipe helps.

Comment: You don't need the relationship. Just add an argument for the author uid.